# issues with BananaPi using XFCE4 + 5" Waveshare touchscreen + Armbian

Tags: xfce, lightdm

I started using Armbian (mainline kernel) for my Banana Pi for Nextcloud and Apache usage, now I wanted to advance the usability of it by connecting a touchscreen to it for basic SmartHome usage (I'm about to code a small Qt application to control lights and heatings etc.).

So I bought a [5" HDMI touchscreen](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD) and installed the drivers as given on the website.

Afterwards, I tried to install XFCE4 [just as explained](https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce#How_to_install_Xfce) and tried to start it resulting in the following error log:

```
[  2615.641] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.2
Release Date: 2017-03-02
[  2615.641] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2615.641] Build Operating System: Linux 4.9.0-4-armmp-lpae armv7l Debian
[  2615.641] Current Operating System: Linux bananapi 4.14.18-sunxi #24 SMP Fri Feb 9 16:24:32 CET 2018 armv7l
[  2615.641] Kernel command line: root=UUID=62fc7248-9a57-4024-90d9-b4767bd2c697 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=tty1 console=ttyS0,115200 hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=1920x1080p60 panic=10 consoleblank=0 loglevel=1 ubootpart=f7477067-01 ubootsource=mmc usb-storage.quirks=0x2537:0x1066:u,0x2537:0x1068:u   sunxi_ve_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_g2d_mem_reserve=0 sunxi_fb_mem_reserve=16 cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1
[  2615.642] Build Date: 16 October 2017  09:48:39AM
[  2615.642] xorg-server 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[  2615.642] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  2615.642]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2615.642] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2615.642] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Feb 23 12:01:01 2018
[  2615.643] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2615.643] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2615.644] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  2615.644] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  2615.644] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  2615.644] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  2615.645] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[  2615.645] (**) |   |-->Device "Allwinner A10/A13 FBDEV"
[  2615.645] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  2615.645] (**) Option "BlankTime" "0"
[  2615.646] (**) Option "StandbyTime" "0"
[  2615.646] (**) Option "SuspendTime" "0"
[  2615.646] (**) Option "OffTime" "0"
[  2615.646] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2615.646] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2615.646] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  2615.646] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  2615.646] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2615.646]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2615.646] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[  2615.646] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2615.646] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  2615.646] (II) Loader magic: 0x667f60
[  2615.646] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2615.646]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2615.646]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  2615.646]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  2615.646]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  2615.650] (++) using VT number 7

[  2615.650] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[  2615.651] (II) no primary bus or device found
[  2615.651] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2615.652] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2615.661] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2615.661]    compiled for 1.19.2, module version = 1.0.0
[  2615.661]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  2615.661] (II) LoadModule: "fbturbo"
[  2615.662] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbturbo
[  2615.662] (II) UnloadModule: "fbturbo"
[  2615.662] (II) Unloading fbturbo
[  2615.663] (EE) Failed to load module "fbturbo" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2615.663] (EE) No drivers available.
[  2615.663] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  2615.663] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[  2615.663] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  2615.663] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  2615.663] (EE) 
[  2615.663] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I looked for lightdm if maybe there was something wrong with it. `systemctl status lightdm` looked as followed:

```
● lightdm.service - Light Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/lightdm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-23 12:01:01 CET; 34s ago
     Docs: man:lightdm(1)
  Process: 7336 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/lightdm (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 7332 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/lightdm" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7336 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 23 12:01:01 bananapi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 23 12:01:01 bananapi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 23 12:01:01 bananapi systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Feb 23 12:01:01 bananapi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 23 12:01:01 bananapi systemd[1]: Failed to start Light Display Manager.
Feb 23 12:01:01 bananapi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 23 12:01:01 bananapi systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As XFCE said there was no screens found (btw the LCD is connected and working but only showing the Armbian logo and a cursor all the time) I'm starting to guess there might be a driver issue, or is there something I missed installing during the procedure?

I don't want to reinstall Armbian using the legacy kernel version with the GUI as it took me millions of nerves to get that Nextcloud running.

EDIT: maybe the `lsmod` output will help someone out there too.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
sun4i_gpadc_iio        16384  0
fuse                   73728  3
evdev                  20480  1
ir_lirc_codec          16384  0
lirc_dev               16384  1 ir_lirc_codec
sun4i_codec            32768  3
sun4i_ts               16384  0
snd_usb_audio         110592  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_soc_core          118784  1 sun4i_codec
sunxi_cir              16384  0
uvcvideo               69632  0
snd_usbmidi_lib        24576  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_rawmidi            24576  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
sun4i_gpadc            16384  0
snd_pcm                65536  3 snd_usb_audio,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_soc_core
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
nvmem_sunxi_sid        16384  0
snd_timer              24576  1 snd_pcm
videobuf2_v4l2         20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_core         28672  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd                    45056  7 snd_hwdep,snd_usb_audio,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sun4i_ss               24576  0
uio_pdrv_genirq        16384  0
uio                    16384  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
bonding                94208  0
brcmfmac              159744  0
brcmutil               16384  1 brcmfmac
cfg80211              376832  1 brcmfmac
rfkill                 20480  2 cfg80211
ip_tables              20480  0
x_tables               20480  1 ip_tables
realtek                16384  1
```

I already tried installing the packages `linux-u-boot-bananapi_5.38_armhf`, `linux-headers-sun7i_5.38_armhf` and `linux-image-sun7i_5.38_armhf`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Xorg log says the server couldn't find the `fbturbo` module. Have you installed `fbturbo` as per http://wiki.lemaker.org/BananaPro/Pi:GPU?